# Submodules in custom React component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I've created a React component library which is getting quite big now, so I want to split it into submodules but am unable to do so.

The current setup is like this:

**src/index.ts**

```
export * from "./components";
export * from "./utils";
```

**src/components/index.ts**

```
export { default as CustomComponentOne } from "./CustomComponentOne";
export { default as CustomComponentTwo } from "./CustomComponentTwo";
```

**src/utils/index.ts**

```
export { default as utilOne } from "./utilOne";
export { default as utilTwo } from "./utilTwo";
```

**package.json**

```json
{
    ...
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "module": "dist/index.modern.js",
    "source": "src/index.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "microbundle-crl --no-compress --no-sourcemap --format modern,cjs",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

My goal is to enable imports like:

```
import { CustomComponentOne } from "my-library/components"
import { utilOne } from "my-library/utils"
```

while preserving imports like

```
import { CustomComponentOne, utilOne } from "my-library"
```

The last import example is how everything is now imported, but I want to add imports like the two above. I was able to do this with compiling the project with `tsc` instead of `microbundle-crl` because this generated a .js file for each .ts file, but `microbundle-crl` creates 1 `.js` file as output. But SCSS files etc were not compiled with `tsc` (obviously).

Does anybody know how to go about this?